# File Uploader preventing button clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a weird one for you...

I have two controls on an ASP page - a file uploader, and a button.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUploadData" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuWizData" runat="server" AllowMultiple="false" />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUploadWizData" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" EnableViewState="true" Text="Upload" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDataUploaded" runat="server" Visible="false">
     Upload complete! Please continue to the next step.
</asp:Panel>
```

Note the OnClick="btnUpload_Click" for the link button. 
I've placed a breakpoint on the first line in `btnUpload_Click`

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlDataUploaded.Visible = true; //Breakpoint here
    pnlUploadData.Visible = false;
}
```

If I click the button without selected a file in the uploader, I hit the breakpoint and everything is great.

If I select a file in the file uploader, then click the button - nothing happens. Literally nothing. No postback occurs.

I've googled it a fair bit and have found other people having this problem (https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/284245/button-click-event-not-firing-with-file-upload-con and [Event of button is not fired when i browse any file through fileupload control and upload it..connection time out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078249/event-of-button-is-not-fired-when-i-browse-any-file-through-fileupload-control-a))

I have tried adding `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2097151" />` to my web config, which didn't work. I also don't have any validators on my page that might be affecting it. 
I've also tried using an ASP Button instead of LinkButton which didn't work. I've even checked out the javascript on the page and the onclick for the link button is correct, but calling the method doesn't do anything (not sure why). 
This is the rendered HTML:

`<a id="MainContent_lrtImportWizard_vtmImportWizard_vtImportData_lbUploadWizData" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$lrtImportWizard$vtmImportWizard$vtImportData$lbUploadWizData", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Upload</a>`

Any assistance would be great! Or any way to even track what could be occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You should set AutoPostBack="true".

When you execute Visible="false", that property will be only changed on server side. But what you see on client(on browser) is affects of html. And you need to update that info to client. AutoPostBack="true" will cause any server side changes to be applied only on the controls.

In addition, you can use java script to hide and unhide your control immediately because javascript is run on client side.